# Is it possible to use part of dict key as column name for table?

Tags: python

I’m working on getting quite big set of data analyzed. It is too big to be processed manually so I need to grab and parse it automatically and the problem is that I’m not a programmer at all and this is my first piece of code ever so I may miss something obvious.

The set is 123 fields for each of 2 700 items, not all the items have data for all the fields and some fields have more than one value. Data is accessible via API responding with JSON file limited to 50 items max per call and I pay for each call. OK, going to problem itself:

I managed to get nested JSON flat with flatten module. Keys in JSON and resulting dict does not have unique for item name so resulting file looks like `{‘item_1_param_1’ : ‘X’, ‘item_1_param_2’ : ‘Y’, … , ‘item_2700_param_123’ : ‘Z’}`.

I’m stuck on this point — I need this dataset to be analyzed as table (in Excel or probably SPSS) but I’m only able to produce a table with 1 column and 2700 row out of it.

What I would be absolutely happy to have is a table like

```
            item_1  item_2     …    item_2700
param_1        X       Y       …       K
param_2        L    [M, N, O]  …       P
…              …       …       …       …
param_123      N/A     Q       …       Z
```

The idea of what was done is the next (pseudocode just to illustrate logic):

```
response = requests.get(url)
output = json.loads(response.text)
flat_json = flatten(output)
```

(The full code is way bigger as this script is meant to be reused later by people who understand programming even less than me so it is full of checks and warnings plus contains some workarounds to correct mistakes in JSON generated on API side)

So is there a way to extract a part of a dict key (like `'item_1'` from `'item_1_param_1'`) and transform 1-column table to multi-column using this part as a column name and assign correct values to it? Thanx a lot in advance for helping newbie!

Comment: It sounds like what you want is something like `{'item_1': {'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 2, ...}, 'item_2': {'param_1': 3, 'param_2': 4, ...}}`. Is this correct?

Comment: technically yes, with this dict structure I think I will be able to go further (using pandas probably)

Comment: You could determine what keys matched a pattern like `'item_'` by iterating over all the keys of the dictionary and seeing which ones matched the pattern. For a simple prefix like that you could simply use `if key.startswith('item_1'):` and for more complicated patterns, use a regular expression via the `regex` module to check them.

Comment: For those who will see this later on and particularly for those who use flatten module to parse JSON -- I got into classic Read Manual Before trap -- the whole problem was caused by the way way flatten module operates -- if it's called as 'flatten(output)' it assign unique key to each and every nested element and the resulting table is 1 column and many raws. But flatten can iterate over data if called as 'flat_json = (flatten(d) for d in output)' and automatically produce the table with raws and columns you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible yes. You can get the keys with `key_list = list(some_dictionary.keys())` then you can say

```
for key in key_list:
    separated_key_names = key.split('_') #separate key name at "_"
    variable1 = " ".join(separated_key_names[0], separated_key_names[1])
    variable2 = " ".join(separated_key_names[2], separated_key_names[3])
```

This will split the key, and make a variable for each name like (item 1, param 1)

You may also be interested in the `some_dictionary.items()` method. You could use this like

```
for key, value in some_dictionary:
    separated_key_names = key.split('_') #separate key name at "_"
    variable1 = " ".join(separated_key_names[0], separated_key_names[1])
    variable2 = " ".join(separated_key_names[2], separated_key_names[3])
    # Now you have separated the variable names, and the key. You can process how you want
    my_info = {(variable1, variable2): value} # for example
```

I'm not sure how you'd like to reassemble the data, but you should be able to manipulate it however you'd like from here. Leave a comment if something is unclear to you in my post!

Comment: Thank you, Reedinationer! I appreciate your explanation of basic things which made a lot clearer the whole problem and solution!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

def identify_item(pair):
    return re.search('item_\d+', pair[0]).group()

gb = groupby(flat_json.items(), key=identify_item)

result = {item_id: {param.replace(item_id, '')[1:]: value 
                    for param, value in param_pair} 
          for item_id, param_pair in gb}
```

This assumes that your data will be of the format specified in the question; otherwise, some tweaking might be necessary.

Example:

```
>>> flat_json = {'item_{}_param_{}'.format(i, j): np.random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(1, 11) for j in range(1, 5)}
>>> # apply transformation
>>> result
{'item_1': {'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 8, 'param_4': 9}, 
 'item_2': {'param_1': 0, 'param_2': 2, 'param_3': 8, 'param_4': 7}, 
 'item_3': {'param_1': 3, 'param_2': 7, 'param_3': 6, 'param_4': 7}, 
 'item_4': {'param_1': 0, 'param_2': 9, 'param_3': 0, 'param_4': 4}, 
 'item_5': {'param_1': 5, 'param_2': 1, 'param_3': 2, 'param_4': 9}, 
 'item_6': {'param_1': 9, 'param_2': 5, 'param_3': 0, 'param_4': 0}, 
 'item_7': {'param_1': 4, 'param_2': 7, 'param_3': 4, 'param_4': 2}, 
 'item_8': {'param_1': 2, 'param_2': 8, 'param_3': 5, 'param_4': 7}, 
 'item_9': {'param_1': 5, 'param_2': 4, 'param_3': 1, 'param_4': 8}, 
 'item_10': {'param_1': 4, 'param_2': 0, 'param_3': 3, 'param_4': 0}}
```

Comment: Thank you, Marcus, that was fast and useful!